# Is this Version Control System Centralized or Distributed?

Tags: version-control, surroundscm

Is [Seapine's Surround SCM](http://www.seapine.com/surroundscm.html) a centralized or a distributed version control system?

Comment: For moderators, this is 100% on topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From their website, specifically [this page](http://www.seapine.com/scmdistributed.html), it is centralized.  They emphasize caching proxies for performance, but there is still one single copy of the repo.

Comment: So in that case it is a centralized VCS?

Comment: Disclaimer: I work at Seapine Software. (That actually kinda helps this question.) It definitely is centralized and usually remote users just connect via TCP/IP. The proxy server is generally used in places, like a remote office, where network speeds to the main server are less than great.